# cucumberjs unexpected token with imported files that has arrow functions

Tags: javascript, cucumber, cucumberjs

I have a class that I'm trying to test with cucumberjs. When I import the class from the feature it gives me the following when I run cucumberjs

Command I execute

```
./node_modules/.bin/cucumber-js ./tests/features
```

Error that I get

```
getAll = () => this.data;
           ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
:

:

:
```

Files

```
// TestApi.js
class TestApi {
    constructor(){
        this.data = ['teststuff', 'teststuff2']
    }

    getAll = () => this.data;
}



//test.feature

const { Before, Given, When, Then } = require('cucumber') 
const { TestApi } = require('../../../api/TestApi.js');
const { TestDomain } = require('../../../domain/domain.js');
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not with CucumberJS, but with the version of NodeJS on your machine. You can check your current version by running the `node -v` command in your terminal. If your version is older than the currently listed LTS release on the [NodeJS website](https://nodejs.org/), the follow the installation instructions.

Online example: https://testjam.io/?p=ZVpoJT4AkNHy9PTxeure